# Rails and Devise: Adding spam protection with acts_as_textcaptcha

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, captcha

I'm trying to add spam protection to my Devise signup form using [acts_as_textcaptcha](https://github.com/matthutchinson/acts_as_textcaptcha), but for some reason it won't show up in my form.

Based on [How To: Use Recaptcha with Devise](https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/wiki/How-To:-Use-Recaptcha-with-Devise). My Rails 6 blog app available here for cloning: https://github.com/anonymous-donor/blog-with-textcaptcha

Thanks!

### Gemfile

```
gem 'acts_as_textcaptcha', '~> 4.5'
```

### models/user.rb

```rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable

  acts_as_textcaptcha
end
```

### controllers/registrations_controller.rb

```rb
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  def new
    @user = User.new
    @user.textcaptcha
  end

  private
    # https://kakimotonline.com/2014/03/30/extending-devise-registrations-controller/
    def sign_up_params
      allow = [:email, :display_name, :password, :password_confirmation, :textcaptcha]
      params.require(resource_name).permit(allow)
    end
end
```

### config/routes.rb

```rb
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users, controllers: {  registrations: "registrations" }
...
end
```

### app/views/devise/registrations/new.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
...
  <%= textcaptcha_fields(f) do %>
    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :textcaptcha_answer, @user.textcaptcha_question %><br/>
      <%= f.text_field :textcaptcha_answer, :value => '' %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
...
<% end %>
```

### config/textcaptcha.yml

```
development:
  questions:
    - question: 'Is ice hot or cold?'
      answers: 'cold'
    - question: 'what color is an orange?'
      answers: 'orange'
    - question: 'what is two plus 3?'
      answers: '5,five'
    - question: 'what is 5 times two?'
      answers: '10,ten'
    - question: 'How many colors in the list, green, brown, foot and blue?'
      answers: '3,three'
    - question: 'what is Georges name?'
      answers: 'george'
    - question: '11 minus 1?'
      answers: '10,ten'
    - question: 'is boiling water hot or cold?'
      answers: 'hot'
    - question: 'what color is my blue shirt today?'
      answers: 'blue'
    - question: 'what is 16 plus 4?'
      answers: '20,twenty'
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if I am wrong can you please say where is this `gem 'acts_as_textcaptcha', '~> 4.5'` ? I can't find this in the link you provided : https://github.com/ambethia/recaptcha. Please follow that gem and post back if there is any problems. You can refer the same page to configure with devise : https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/wiki/How-To:-Use-Recaptcha-with-Devise. Thank you.

Comment: What are you talking about?

Answer (score 0):

Turned out I had to had to set `config.cache_store = :null_store` to `config.cache_store = :memory_store` in `config/environments/development.rb` for it to work in development mode.